# How to validate a Twitter username using Regex

Tags: php, regex, validation, twitter

I have used the pattern `/[a-z0-9_]+/i` within the function:

```
function validate_twitter($username) {
 if (eregi('/[a-z0-9_]+/i', $username)) {
  return true;
 }
}
```

With this, I test if the input is a valid twitter username, but i'm having difficulties as it  is not giving me a valid result.

Can someone help me find a solution.

Comment: Note that ereg* functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0, use preg_* functions instead, preg_match in this case.

Comment: Showing us the input, expected output and actual output will also be of help to us...

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766158/php-to-replace-username-with-link-to-twitter-account

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To validate if a string is a valid Twitter handle:

```
function validate_username($username)
{
    return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/', $username);
}
```

If you are trying to match `@username` within a string.

For example: `RT @username: lorem ipsum @cjoudrey etc...`

Use the following:

```
$string = 'RT @username: lorem ipsum @cjoudrey etc...';
preg_match_all('/@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})/', $string, $usernames);
print_r($usernames);
```

You can use the latter with [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to linkify usernames in a string.

Edit: Twitter also [open sourced text libraries](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html) for Java and Ruby for matching usernames, hash tags, etc.. You could probably look into the code and find the regex patterns they use.

Edit (2): Here is a PHP port of the Twitter Text Library: https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php#readme

Comment: The above pattern will also match email addresses e.g. someone@email.com will return @email which obviously isn't intended as a Twitter username. I fixed this with the addition of a negative lookahead (?![.A-Za-z]) Full string: /@([A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15})(?![.A-Za-z])/

Comment: Isn't [A-Za-z0-9_] same as \w

Comment: @KryptoniteDove's comment should be used as the answer here as it is correct and overcomes an annoying problem. Can you update please? http://regexr.com/38pig

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `/` with `ereg*`.

In fact, don't use `ereg*` at all if you can avoid it. http://php.net/preg_match

*edit*: Note also that `/[a-z0-9_]+/i` will match on `spaces are invalid` and `not-a-real-name`. You almost certainly want `/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i`.

S

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you're using the PCRE form, in which case you should be using the [preg_match](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function instead.

Answer (score 2):

`eregi()` won't expect any `/` or additional toggles. Just use `eregi('[a-z0-9_]+')`

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is valid, although it allows spaces FYI. (If you want to test out regular expressions I recommend: http://rubular.com/).

The first issue here is your use of `eregi` which is deprecated as of PHP 5.3. It is recommended that you use `preg_match` instead, it has the same syntax. Give that a try and see if it helps.

PHP Documentation for preg_match: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
PHP Documentation for eregi:      http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php

Answer (score 2):

Twitter user names have from 1 to 15 chars... so this could be even better with `/^[a-z0-9_]{1,15}$/i`.

Comment: I think, Twitter allows a minimum of 3 characters in their usernames.

Comment: I think it does now, but previously users were able to register shorter user names (like [@a](https://twitter.com/a)), so you'd still need to use a minimum of 1 character to catch these.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Where did you find the charset? I mean, where did you read that Twitter usernames can be [A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15} ?

Comment: Ok, I searched in Twitter's open source code, and I found that it actually is /[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}/ . Source: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/blob/24c513652e3ece6853b77575b60206617ce26fd3/twitter-text.js#L215

Comment: @Qualcuno, I believe that's the limit of your real name. The handle limit is 15 everywhere I look.