# Php to replace @username with link to twitter account

Tags: php, regex

I assume this is some to do with regex, but it's an art all it's own - and I need some help.

When we display a story, we store all the text in a varilable - let's say $story.

What i'd like is to do a str_replace (I think that's what I need) that says something like this "If the text contains @something then turn it into a link like `<a href="http://www.twitter.com/something">@something</a>`- but only do this if there's nothing before the @ symbol" (to exclude email addresses)

Also, we'd need to stop the 'something' if there's a space or punctuation after it. so that @something. doesn't turn into `<a href="http://www.twitter.com/something.">@something.</a>`

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$input = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i',
                      '$1<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>',
                       $input);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/aGklx)

It matches a `@` which is preceded by whitespace or nothing ( when it is at the beginning).

It can also be shorted using positive lookbehind as:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(?<=^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i',
                      '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>',
                      $input);
```

Which matches only the twitter name but only if there is space or nothing before that.

Comment: The second argument (to the second example) should be `<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1">$1</a>`.

Comment: Hey, I am learning regex and this example is very useful to me. I get almost all of the first example, but dont understand what the /i at the end of the first pattern means. someone care to explain?

Comment: @0al0: the `i` at the end makes the regex case insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

A positive lookbehind could do the trick:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\s)@(.*?)/', '<a href="....com/$1">@$1</a>')
```

going off the top of my head. "If there's a @ which is preceded by something which is whitespace, then take whatever follows after the @ and do the html tag wrapping".

Comment: Well, you'd want `[a-z0-9_-]` instead of the `.` in the regex, right?  Since the twitter name can't have special characters or spaces (which your regex would pick up right now.  In fact, it'd eat till the end of the string)...

Comment: Fails when there is a twitter name right at the beginning without a space before it.

Comment: This is finding the "@" symbol, and creating a link - but doesn't use the text following the @ in either the URL or what's displayed. So what I see is `<a href='http://www.twitter.com'>@</a>`

Comment: @scatteredbomb, you're right. `(.*?)` will match nothing if possible. Seeing as nothing follows, this will always be the case.