# PHP Regex Pattern to Match "@user" Anywhere

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This regex pattern stuff is confusing to me.

I have a username like `@tom` stored in a variable. I would like to set up a pattern to match `@tom` when it's found anywhere in the string; beginning, middle or end.

My goal is to match and then replace with the link to his profile page. I think I've got it figured out but it's not recognizing the end of a word. As in when it looks for `@tom` it also matches with `@tommy` which is not what I want.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$pattern = array();
$pattern[0] = '/'.$possible1.'/i';

$replacement = array();
$replacement[0] = '$1<a href="http://banterme.com/'.$possible1user.'">@'.$possible1user.'</a>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

I use an array because I want to match all the @'s in the text (ex: @tom is with @inga), not just one. I simplified the actual code to show only one part of the array.

**UPDATE:** Basically, I'm trying to figure out what `'/'.$possible1.'/i'` should be to not match (for example) `@tom` to `@tommy`.

Comment: Use a lookahead assertion: `@tom(?!\w)` this will match @tom that isn't followed by `\w` aka `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV this worked. I would mark it as the solution if it wasn't here as a comment.

Comment: Thanks ^^ I'm willing to let @reikyoushin to take the points, so just accept his answer :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php to replace @username with link to twitter account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766158/php-to-replace-username-with-link-to-twitter-account)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>is this good enough? `/(?!\w)\@tom(?!\w)/`?</strike>
<strike>i just added boundaries..</strike>

the one given by @HamZa DzCyberDeV as comment above is shorter `/\@tom(?!\w)/`

you can check here:

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

with data as `@tom @tomato @atom @tom`

which will return 
`@tomato @atom`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use str_replace?

```
str_replace ("@tom" , "<a href='/users/tom'>@tom</a>" , $text);
```

It doesnt sound like you need regex for this.

Comment: With this you'll get `@tommy` also replaced which will result into `<a href='/users/tom'>@tom</a>my`

Comment: the question was "a username like @tom" which I guess would include the things like @dave too

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for a pattern that doesn't match `@tom` to `@tommy`. Basically, what `'/'.$possible1.'/i'` should be changed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('/@([\w]+)[^\w]/', '<href="http://banterme.com/$1">@$1</a> ', '@tom met @dave somewhere', -1, $count);
```