# How to find @username in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string

What is the best way to find `@username` in a string?

At first I was exploding the string based on `@`'s found, but it seemed like a lot of trouble going through each of the instances.

Can I use regex for this to find all `@usernames` in a string?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424179/twitter-username-regex-validation

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. RegEx is the right way to go:

```
if (preg_match_all('!@(.+)(?:\s|$)!U', $text, $matches))
    $usernames = $matches[1];
else
    $usernames = array(); // empty list, no users matched
```

Comment: Hmm, working good.  But if i have @ pearl-jam in my string, it is only picking up pearl.  any ideas?

Comment: @Mike i changed the regex to use whitespace (`\s`) as delimiter instead of word boundary (`\b`), because `-` is a word boundary in regex, too. it should now match `@pearl-jam`, but will also match `@foo(bar)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use strpos() instead

for references http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```