# If php finds certain text make it a link

Tags: php, regex

So i have a function that outputs saved tweets on my site `<?=stripslashes($row['tweet_text'])?>` And for tweets that have content such as `@user` i want to be linked. So how would i make it that if it finds the letter `@` so it turns the text connected to it into a link that would go to `www.twitter.com/user`

So if it finds text such as `@username` it will make it into a link

`<a href="http://www.twitter.com/username">@username</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?= preg_replace('/@(\w+)/', '<a href="https://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', stripslashes($row['tweet_text']))?>
```

For hash tag:

```
<?= preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/$#$1">#$1</a>', stripslashes($row['tweet_text']))?>
```

Comment: to match a twitter username, you should use `/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/` as found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424179/twitter-username-regex-validation

Comment: @Nile word characters (letters, digits, and underscores)

Comment: I'm not to fluent with regex besides some basic principles. Is `[A-Za-z0-9_]` equivalent to `\w`?

Comment: Awesome this works. But what does the @$1 signify just curious?

Comment: How would i be able to add more such as if it found a #hastag tag it would search into `https://twitter.com/#!/search/$#hashtag`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
<?php

$text = 'asd asd asd asd as @user aasda sad asd @yyy sd';

$text = preg_replace('/(.*?)\@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(.*?)/', '$1<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>$3', $text);

?>
```

Anything that has a @+A-Za-z0-9_ will be changed to the link ...

Comment: So what about just  `@user @yyy`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do a `preg_match_all` to fetch the username(s), assuming that the username does not include any white-spaces:

```
$usernames = preg_match_all( "|\@(.*) |" , stripslashes($row['tweet_text']) , $match );

$usernames = $match[0];

//loop through usernames and do whatever (replace, get data, etc etc)
```

If you just want to replace all usernames with `http://twitter.com/username`, then just use `preg_replace` on your output:

```
preg_replace('|\@(.*)|', '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>', stripslashes($row['tweet_text']))
```