# Strip all whitespace and include @ at beginning of Username

Tags: php, regex

So this post is in two parts:

I have found a few different ways of either removing whitespace at the beginning & end of a string or sending out an error if there is any whitespace - but how can I remove all whitespace in a string ($name)? < By this if someone enters their full name with spaces the script should automatically put their first and last name together without the whitespace without putting out error.

Also, how can I make sure a @ sign is a default at the beginning of the string like the twitter username?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate a Twitter username using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424179/how-to-validate-a-twitter-username-using-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by whitespace you mean the space character then you can use `str_replace`:

```
$string = 'There are two  spaces here .';
echo str_replace(' ', '', $string); //Outputs "Therearetwospaceshere."
```

If you need to strip line-breaks, or tabs as well as spaces look at using `preg_replace`:

```
$string = "There are two  spaces and a \n line break here.";
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string); //Outputs "Therearetwospacesandalinebreakhere."
```

For validating that the string begins with an `@` sign I would use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^@/', $string))
   echo 'Begins with @';
else
   echo 'Does not being with @';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [**str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$name = 'bill harrison jones';
$name = '@'.str_replace(' ', '', $name);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/6Ygsp8YT)

Comment: what about multiple white spaces, tabs, newlines ? :D

Comment: @Twisted1919 - oh you are so twisted! :D +1

Comment: @Twisted1919 This will handle multiple whitespace. Tabs, New lines, however, no... :)

Comment: @MarkM - no worries, was mostly a funny addition :)

Comment: @MarkM - OP did not ask for newlines, so I think you are good :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim) to remove the whitespace at the beginning and end of a string:

   ```
    $string = " hello ";
    $newstring = strim($string);
    echo $newstring; // outputs "hello"
   ```

If you want to remove **all** whitespace from a string, you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
    $string = "hello
    hello ";
    $newstring = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
    echo $newstring; // outputs "hellohello"
```

2. You can check the beginning character using [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

   ```
    $string = "@esqew";
    if (preg_match('/@([\w]+)/', $string) == 1) {
        // string starts with "@"
    }
   ```

<sub>[**Debuggex**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iT8S45iBkFW9ynAo/0)</sub>

Please be careful though, as Twitter usernames follow a much [stricter regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4424179/269970) than you might think.

Comment: That last regex will do a contains not starts with. Needs a `^`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is confusing. It sounds like you have already solved your problem. Nonetheless, `str_replace` is the function you want.

Your second ought to belong in a separate question. However, a string is an array of characters. So I imagine the following would work

```
$name = array_unshift($name, '@');
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing all space and white space ( like break ) use this

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

For check `@`

```
if($string[0] != '@')
  echo 'Error';
else
//do something
```

If you want to add `@` when username is without `@` use this code

```
$string = '@' . ltrim($string,'@');
```